# Usage based billing for hosting a REST API

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku

I currently hosting my website on a combination of Amazon S3 and Cloudfront. These services have a usage-based billing. When there are no users visiting my website, I am paying next to nothing.

Now I wanted to create a simple REST API where users can invite other users. I thought about using node.js or sinatra. But when I want to host that, I need to start at least one EC2 node, which roughly costs 120$ a year. I know both Heroku and AWS have free tier options, but I am explicitly looking for usage-based billing.

Is there a service that allows usage-based billing (eg. number of requests) for a custom REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [AWS's API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway) provides the REST API part, with billing ...

> Low-Cost and Efficient
>
> With Amazon API Gateway, you pay only for calls
>   made to your APIs and data transfer out. There are no minimum fees or
>   upfront commitments.

but you'll still have to point it at a back end service.  EC2 would incur the costs you mention, but if your 'action' is simple, you may be able to use [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda).  It to is priced based on number of requests and actual compute time.

Comment: Of course, the back-end could be AWS Lambda, persisting data in dynamodb, simpledb, S3 or other services, avoiding continuously-running instances... depending on what the back-end needs to do.